# can the expression (give it a go) be broken up

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Is this sentence grammatically and stylistically correct, or is it very weird:

> He insisted to give it yet another quick go

Comment: The only important thing is that the context be sufficient to convey (to that specific audience) the sense of "go" being used.

Comment: I prefer "He insisted on giving it a go yet again."

Comment: 'Giving something a go' is sufficiently informal that both are possible. Don't say (or write) 'he insisted to give', rather 'he insisted on giving'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, I don't think anything is wrong with the sentence but as Michael Harvey said, the following sentence may be better.

> He insisted on giving it yet another quick go.

OR

> He insisted on giving it a go, yet another time.

Both are correct, either way.